# Pass unique_ptr to the function that waits pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Here's a function [IDXGISwapChain::GetBuffer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that awaits for **ppSurface. If I'll create the pointer like this:

```
unique_ptr<ID3D11Texture2D> backBuffer;
```

how can I pass it?

Comment: You should not use `unique_ptr` with COM interface pointer. Smart pointer calls `delete` in destructor, but COM interface pointer requires Release call. Result of `delete` operation on COM interface pointer is undefined. Instead of `uniquie_ptr` you should use COM smart pointer, like `_com_ptr_t`

Comment: @AlexFarber Of course you can always add a custom deleter to your `unique_ptr` that calls `Release` on the COM object instead of deleting it.

Comment: @ComicSansMS But how to pass this pointer in my example, where function needs pointer to pointer?

Comment: @nikitablack `GetBuffer` uses the Buffer as an output parameter, so you don't want to pass the contents of the `unique_ptr` here. Instead, create a local raw pointer to `ID3D11Texture2D` and pass an address to _that_. Then update your `unique_ptr` accordingly after the `GetBuffer` returns.

Comment: @ComicSansMS - this may be nice C++ programming trick, but it is really better to use existing COM ptr wrapper.

Comment: @AlexFarber True. Just because you can do it does not mean it's the best solution for the problem.

Comment: @ComicSansMS So, if I pass raw_pointer (that is COM object) to unique_ptr with deleter then I don't need to care about raw_pointer anymore? It will be released automatically after exiting scope together with unique_ptr?

Comment: @nikitablack Correct.